# Increase IDA's 256 xref limit

Tags: ida

I am writing a plugin which relies on going through all xrefs to printf-like function (you can imagine how many xrefs there are). After setting number of shown xrefs to 300 IDA has rounded to 256 what seems to be the maximum. I thought it is just GUI limitiation so I tried iterating over XrefsTo() programmatically which as well yielded only 256 xrefs. After quicky skimming through config I found nothing.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Sounds very strange: I've seen thousands of references to a log function I worked with in IDA, and all of them were iterable. Would you tell us which processor is it, which IDA version are you using, etc ?

Comment: Sounds very odd to me too. Worked with upwards of 10K xrefs without any issues.

Comment: Is this IDA pro or the demo version?

Comment: I use IDA Demo 6.8. I tried it on both Linux and Windows. The executable is armv7 Mach-O. It might just be some demo limitation but hex-rays page didn't mention any such limitation so it's at least confusing.

Comment: I created a small test executable in IDA Demo 6.8 and I was able to display more than 256 xrefs

Comment: (Also, the `XrefsTo` function only exists in IDAPython, which does not appear to be included in IDA Demo 6.8 so I cannot reproduce this, but it does seem to work in the GUI)